# Having 2 forms on same page but only loading second after first is submitted

Tags: php, html, postback

So what i want do is, have a form displayed on load where it asks user for their details such as name etc, then once the user clicks submit, i want that information to carry over to the next form, i know i have to hidden fields for that.

I want another form to be displayed after they click submit, this all has to be done using POSTBACK, so pretty much having 2 forms on one php page but only displaying the second one after the first has been submitted.

I know i can do this by creating two different php files and using header but i would like to learn how to do it via postback.

```
 <form name="firstform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> "       onSubmit="return validator();">
 <p>Please fill in the following form</p>
 <p>Given Name*  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/><br/>
     Middle Name <input type="text" name="mname"/><br />
     Family Name* <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/><br />
     Chosen Username* <input type="text" name="uname"/>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>&nbsp;
  </form>

  <form name="secondform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " >
    Test* <input type = "text" name="test"/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and Javascript if this is just a quick form

There is a nice [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that allows you to send an HTML form asynchroniously.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Hide all forms
        $('form').hide();

        // Show the first form
        $('form').eq(0).show();

        $('form').eq(0).on('submit', function() {
            // Submit via ajax




            // Unhide second form
            $(this).hide();
            $('form').eq(1).show();

            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would validate that the first forms data is correct, then test to see if the form has been submitted without errors.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($errors)) {
    // Output second form
} else { 
    // Output first form
}
```

You would either send the first set of data to the database or you can add them as hidden fields in the second form.

This is assuming you put any generated errors in to an array called $errors.